# TortoiseSVN - no overlay icons in a VM with Windows 10 on a shared Mac folder

Tags: windows, macos, tortoisesvn, vmware-fusion, truecrypt

I have a MacBook Pro with OS 10.11.5 and Vmware Fusion 8.1.1 is installed.
In Fusion I have a Windows 10 (64 Bit, Ent.) running, where I have a (vmware) shared folder from the Mac OS. 
This shared folder contains a Subversion Repository which is on the Mac in an encrypted Volume (a TrueCrypt-Volume mounted with VeraCrypt).

To see these handy overlay icons in Windows (if files changed etc.) I installed TortoiseSVN (64 bit, 1.9.4), but no Overlay Icons are visible in W10.

I tried the solutions in: [TortoiseSVN icons overlay not showing after updating to Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964627/tortoisesvn-icons-overlay-not-showing-after-updating-to-windows-10) but all the hints there didn't help.
I think the issue is related to Fusion's shared folder, because local repos do show overlay icons in W10. 
I activated all drive checkboxes in TortoiseSVN settings but nothing changed.

I know that it is not a good idea to share a repo through different OS: [SVN control of a shared virtual machine folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159173/svn-control-of-a-shared-virtual-machine-folder)
but I don't want to do any commit stuff (anymore) in Windows, I just want to see the overlay icons, which are missing in Mac's OS X subversion.
And even with TortoiseSVN installed, I can commit files on the Mac without errors, if I just never touch the commit or checkout functions in W10-TortoiseSVN.

Is there anything else, I can do to see these useful overlay icons?

Thanks
frank

Comment: By the way, the Overlay Icons are neither shown if I use a Windows 10 VM on a Windows 8.1 Host with VMware Worksation 12 Pro (Version 12.1.1). Also here I checked all "Drive Types" in the TortoiseSVN Settings and did a reboot. So either this is a TortoiseSVN or a VMware bug I think now.

Comment: OK, I wrote the issue to the [TortoiseSVN mailinglist](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3177895) I hope that there will be a solution.

Comment: Hm. Two answers, not solving it and then silence. Seems nobody is haveing this same and special scenario and so this bug won't be fixed, as I cannot fix it :(

Comment: Does this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/49535879/2338477 ?

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN does not show status icons for working copies located on network shares, by default. Read the [FAQ | Why are the icons only visible on local and not on network drives?](https://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#ovlonlylocal).

And don't confuse Subversion [working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy) with a [repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.repository).

Comment: As I wrote: " I activated all drive checkboxes in TortoiseSVN settings but nothing changed." this was maybe misunderstandable, I ment with it, that I checked also "Network Drives" in "Drive Types" in the TortoiseSVN Settings.
Sorry to confuse working copy with repo, this is different, right!